# Parsing JSON Feed

Tags: php, json, parsing, string-parsing, php-parser

I have a json feed in a URL that contains following data.

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
[{"ID":1123,"OrderNumber":"1394","ProjectType":"Postcard","Template":"WtlossStudy solo","TemplateURL":"someone.biz/Home/ShowTemplate/283","ShipDate":"2/28/2015","InHomeDate":"3/2/2015","Quantity":"10,000","Price":"$3,000","CallTracking":"0"},{"ID":1123,"OrderNumber":"1413","ProjectType":"Postcard","Template":"WtlossStudy solo","TemplateURL":"","ShipDate":"3/30/2015","InHomeDate":"3/31/2015","Quantity":"5,000","Price":"$1,500","CallTracking":"0"},{"ID":1123,"OrderNumber":"1413","ProjectType":"Postcard","Template":"WtlossStudy solo","TemplateURL":"","ShipDate":"4/13/2015","InHomeDate":"4/14/2015","Quantity":"5,000","Price":"$1,500","CallTracking":"0"}]
</string>
```

I need to get it and parse it thorough php. But it is giving invalid foreach error with the following code. Can anyone help me on how to show in correctly.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://someurl.biz/api/api/1123');

$obj = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($obj as $ob) {
    echo $ob->ID;
}
```

Comment: Since you're using the `true` flag in `json_decode()` you should echo array items, not objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try as

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://superiorpostcards.biz/api/api/1123');
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$array = json_decode($obj, true);
foreach($array as $value){
    echo $value['ID'];
}
```

Comment: Even after the first `json_decode` the string is in JSON format only that's why @PHPhil

Answer (score 1):

This works.

As your JSON has become an associative array, you have to make 2 foreach.

- Top foreach parses the 3 "objects" in '[object1, object2, object3]'
- Bottom foreach parses each "object" content

  ```
  $data = json_decode('[{"ID":1123,"OrderNumber":"1394","ProjectType":"Postcard","Template":"WtlossStudy solo","TemplateURL":"someone.biz/Home/ShowTemplate/283","ShipDate":"2/28/2015","InHomeDate":"3/2/2015","Quantity":"10,000","Price":"$3,000","CallTracking":"0"},{"ID":1123,"OrderNumber":"1413","ProjectType":"Postcard","Template":"WtlossStudy solo","TemplateURL":"","ShipDate":"3/30/2015","InHomeDate":"3/31/2015","Quantity":"5,000","Price":"$1,500","CallTracking":"0"},{"ID":1123,"OrderNumber":"1413","ProjectType":"Postcard","Template":"WtlossStudy solo","TemplateURL":"","ShipDate":"4/13/2015","InHomeDate":"4/14/2015","Quantity":"5,000","Price":"$1,500","CallTracking":"0"}]');

   foreach($data as $obj) {
       foreach($obj as $key=>$val) {
          echo $key."->".$val." | ";
       }
   }
  ```

Yes it is simpler with JS. But php "json" is not a JS object, it is an array of associative arrays.

Comment: thanks for your effort.. it work when i use the json feed instead the url but i wanted to work with URL. Already got the solution. Thank you again :)

Comment: Welcome, enjoy coding. Gimme a +1 and a check, if my answer is correct. That will drive readers. Cheers (btw, when is the best time to visit SriLanka ?)

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_array_for_parsing = json_decode(/** put the json here */);
```

this gives you the JSon as php **associative** array.

---

```
$my_array_for_parsing = json_decode($json);
foreach ($my_array_for_parsing as $name => $value) {
    // This will loop three times:
    //     $name = a
    //     $name = b
    //     $name = c
    // ...with $value as the value of that property
}
```

Comment: Where did I not ? In php, you dont have a JSON, you only can get an **associative array**. `json_decode`do the conversion. JSon is a `javascript` object. "php json" is an associative array.

Comment: The part about the foreach output not being correct. The OP returns an array with JSON, not objects which he is trying to output.

Comment: i post a new answer. Working

Answer (score 0):

If second parameter of [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.json-decode.php) is set to `true`, your `json` will be transformed in associative array instead of object. Try this:

```
$obj = json_decode($json, false);

foreach($obj as $ob) {
    echo $ob->ID;
}
```

Comment: didnt help 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: Make sure that `$obj` is not empty. What is the output of `var_dump( $obj );`

Comment: string(668) "[{"ID":1123,"OrderNumber":"1394","ProjectType":"Postcard","Template":"WtlossStudy solo","TemplateURL":"someone.biz/Home/ShowTemplate/283","ShipDate":"2/28/2015","InHomeDate":"3/2/2015","Quantity":"10,000","Price":"$3,000","CallTracking":"0"},{"ID":1123,"OrderNumber":"1413","ProjectType":"Postcard","Template":"WtlossStudy solo","TemplateURL":"","ShipDate":"3/30/2015","InHomeDate":"3/31/2015","Quantity":"5,000","Price":"$1,500","CallTracking":"0"}]"

Comment: Can you paste a whole code (updated) in your question?